# Column Sorting Toggle in Output PDF

Tags: tables

I'm interested in creating a table with columns that can be actively sorted in an output PDF.

In this manner, I mean a table in which one can sort each column either alphabetically or numerically, just like the functionality that is available in this example: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ .

If anyone can point me in the right direction, or even let me know if this functionality is available in a prepackaged tool, it would be very much appreciated. The solution doesn't necessarily need to be confined to TEX. It's just that TEX is what I've been using for typesetting PDFs for sometime, so it's the process I'm used to.

Comment: Welcome! Don't try to do this in a PDF. Even if it is doable, it will not be usable by most readers. You would need something like Java. Many PDF viewers won't support it and those that do will typically have it disabled by default for security reasons. PDF is intended as a static format and it does not really work that well dynamically. You can do simple things, but it is a stretch. For something like this, it would be much better to create the table in a format designed for this kind of purpose.